# How to find an element in an array of records in Purescript

Tags: purescript

everyone.
I'd like to find an element in an array of records in Purescript but since I'm not familiar with Purescripot, I can't solve it.

I have an array `banks` which contains bank records.

This is the type of bank record.

```
type Bank = {
  id :: Int,
  name :: String
}
```

I want to get a bank in `banks` whose id is the same as a given search id.

I tried as following:

```
find (_.id == searchId) banks
```

but getting this error.

```
Could not match type
    Int
  with type
    Function
      { id :: t0
      | t1
      }
```

Please help me with this simple issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `_.id` is a function that takes a `Bank` and returns its `id` (a bit oversimplifying, but good enough for now).

To illustrate:

```
getId = _.id
bank = { id: 42, name: "my bank" }
getId bank == 42
```

And then you take that function and try to compare it with `searchId`, which I'm assuming is a number.

Well, you can't compare functions with numbers, and that's what the compiler is telling you: "*Could not match type Int with type Function*"

The function `find` expects to get as its first argument a function that takes a `Bank` and returns a `Boolean`. There are many ways to produce such a function, but the most obvious one would be with a lambda abstraction:

```
\bank -> bank.id == searchId
```

So to plug it into your code:

```
find (\bank -> bank.id == searchId) banks
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code like this.

```
find(\{id} -> id == searchId) banks
```

So you can get the result object.